# Apache mod_rewrite file in main directory to be in fake directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have all of my website files in one directory and am trying to create a nested linking appearance. The code I have only grabs the first rule and applies it, but I'd like to specify where each URL gets redirected to. Right now both of these rules pull up how-we-invest.php.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?how-it-works(/.*)?$ how-we-invest.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?how-it-works(/.*)?$ pricing.php [L,NC]
```

In my head it seems I should be able to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?how-it-works/how-we-invest/?$ how-we-invest.php [L,NC]
```

So, ideally when you go to website.com/how-it-works/how-we-invest/ it would pull in how-we-invest.php which sits in the root directory.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try RewriteRule ^(how\-it\-works)/(how\-we\-invest\?)$ how-we-invest.php [L,NC] or RewriteRule ^(how-it-works)/(how-we-invest\?)$ how-we-invest.php (not sure about the dash escaping)

Comment: Thanks! The parenthesis did the trick and the trailing slash was fine in there: 

`RewriteRule ^(how-it-works)/(how-we-invest)/?$ how-we-invest.php [L,NC]`